# How to avoid navigation menu being wrapped when shrinking the browser?

Tags: html, css

I have a question. I wrote a simple drop down menu program in HTML & CSS and when shrinking the browser, the navigation menu items (list) are getting wrapped (going to the next line). How can I avoid it ? This is the code :

```
<style>


#coolMenu,
#coolMenu ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#coolMenu {
    float: left;
}
#coolMenu > li {
    float: left;
}
#coolMenu li a {
display: block;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#coolMenu ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
}
#coolMenu ul li a {
    width: 80px;
}
#coolMenu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}


/* Main menu
------------------------------------------*/
#coolMenu {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #2f8be8;
}
#coolMenu > li > a {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#coolMenu > li:hover > a {
    background: #f09d28;
    color: #000;
}

/* Submenu
------------------------------------------*/
#coolMenu ul {
    background: #f09d28;
}
#coolMenu ul li a {
    color: #000;
}
#coolMenu ul li:hover a {
    background: #ffc97c;
}



</style>



<ul id="coolMenu">
    <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mauricii</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Periher</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Hellenico</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Genere</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Indulgentia</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Tyrio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Quicumque</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks.

Isaac

Answer (score 0):

Just add `width: [pixels here]` to the style for `#coolMenu`. Set it to the width you want so the menu always displays as one line. You can also use `min-width:` depending on the rest of your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `min-width`:

```
#coolMenu {
    float: left;
    min-width: 450px;
}
```

See working fiddle: [Min-Width Menu](http://jsfiddle.net/zHqcZ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I you do not want to add a min-width (because you might not know the content of your menu in advance) you can also go for a version with `inline-block`s and add `white-space: no-wrap` to prevent line-breaks. Something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/RpVpk/

These are the lines in your css that changed:

```
#coolMenu {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#coolMenu > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Personaly I prefer the floating version and the line-wrap however. Nobady likes a horizontal scrollbar, and with the variety of screen sizes today... Perhaps you should consider going responsive and add some media-queries?...

**edit:**
for full IE compatibility you may have to change the `li`css to this:

```
#coolMenu > li {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

`white-space` should be IE8+ compatible according to this: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/white-space , but I have no way to test this cause I am on a mac...

Comment: This one is working good in FireFox but not in IE(10) though.

Comment: I have no IE available here (lucky me!), but white-space should be IE8+ compatible. Have you tried the IE inline block hack (add `*display:  inline; zoom:1;`)?

Comment: Thanks, yes, its working in IE with your "display:inline; zoom:1" but not in FireFox. I think I might have to have 2 different files, one for IE and other one for FF. Did not check with Chrome yet.

Comment: don't forget the asterisk in front of the `*display: inline;` This should make sure the code gets only executed by IE and you should be safe with one stylesheet then.